# Adding Oauth 2 token to wp_remote_get request

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, get

I am working on integrating an external API through Wordpress.
The api requries an Oauth 2 token in the header, and i have managed to do that with curl request, but I am curious if that is possible to do through wp_remote_get?
This is the token 4342390_fb2654c5394409da526293bd43f837ce6aa06d0a

Comment: good day dear Milos - very iteresting question. did you try out to do this with wp_remote_get? Look forward to hear from you. Greetings

Comment: No that's why my question is, is it possible to do with wp_remote_get?